# How to reamin my search value on combo at jsp after form submit?

Tags: jsp, search

Pls anyone help me ,my problem
I am using search in my jsp application.
its the search for Staff Name .
After filling these fields and controller search successfully and the results are displayed on the same page below my search fields.
Now my problem is i want that after the submission and search the values of the search fields should remain on the search form as it was.

I am using like :

```
<select name="requestType" id="select" class="form-control" onchange="dropDownOnChange(this);">
    <option value="">&lt;&lt; Select One &gt;&gt;</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>                            
    <option value="staffName">Staff Name</option>
    <option value="leaveType">Leave Type</option>
    <option value="Year">Year</option>
</select>   

<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to select the search item once the page loaded.

1. At your backend, you will receive the search value by name `requestType`, and when you response, set the value into request, such as `request.setAttribute("requestType", seachedValue)`
2. in your jsp page, create an input hidden next the select element to store the requestType get from the response. `<input type="hidden" value="${requestType}"/>`.
3. at the bottom of your jsp page or use jQuery ready function, get the `input[hidden]` value, and use the javascript to select the option.

   `var searchType = $('select[name="searchType"]').next('input').value();
   $('select[name="searchType"] option').each(function(){
       $(this).removeAttr('selected');
       if($(this).value() === searchType) {
           $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
       }
   });`